# Toggling nested state object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I have a state object that contains an array of objects:

```
this.state = {
  feeling: [
    { name: 'alert', status: false },
    { name: 'calm', status: false },
    { name: 'creative', status: false },
    { name: 'productive', status: false },
    { name: 'relaxed', status: false },
    { name: 'sleepy', status: false },
    { name: 'uplifted', status: false }
  ]
}
```

I want to toggle the boolean `status` from true to false on click event. I built this function as a click handler but it doesn't connect the event into the state change:

```
buttonToggle = (event) => {
  event.persist();
  const value = !event.target.value

  this.setState( prevState => ({
    status: !prevState.status
  }))
}
```

I'm having a hard time following the control flow of the nested React state change, and how the active event makes the jump from the handler to the state object and vice versa.

The whole component:

```
export default class StatePractice extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      feeling: [
        { name: 'alert', status: false },
        { name: 'calm', status: false },
        { name: 'creative', status: false },
        { name: 'productive', status: false },
        { name: 'relaxed', status: false },
        { name: 'sleepy', status: false },
        { name: 'uplifted', status: false }
      ]
    }
  }

  buttonToggle = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    const value = !event.target.value

    this.setState( prevState => ({
      status: !prevState.status
    }))
  }



  render() {
    return (  
      <div>
        { this.state.feeling.map(
            (stateObj, index) => { 
              return <button 
                key={ index }
                onClick={ this.buttonToggle } 
                value={ stateObj.status } >
                  { stateObj.status.toString() }
                </button>
            }
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: _I want to toggle the boolean status from true to false on click event._ In all objects or specific one?

Comment: Your initial state contains array of objects, but further you pass _**single**_ object into `setState`. This is likely the problem.

Comment: @hindmost - I just want to toggle the status on one item at a time - the one that gets clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a nested object in a react state object is tricky. You have to get the entire object from the state in a temporary variable, update the value within that variable and then replace the state with the updated variable.
To do that, your buttonToggle function needs to know which button was pressed.

```
return <button 
  key={ index }
  onClick={ (event) => this.buttonToggle(event, stateObj.name) } 
  value={ stateObj.status } >
    { stateObj.status.toString() }
  </button>
```

And your buttonToggle function could look like this

```
buttonToggle = (event, name) => {
  event.persist();

  let { feeling } = this.state;
    let newFeeling = [];

  for (let index in feeling) {
    let feel = feeling[index];
    if (feel.name == name) {
        feel = {name: feel.name, status: !feel.status};
    }
    newFeeling.push(feel);
  }

  this.setState({
    feeling: newFeeling,
  });
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/wedhunop/19/) a working JSFiddle.

Alternatively, if you don't need to store any more data per feeling than "name" and "status", you could rewrite your component state like this:

```
 feeling: {
    alert: false,
    calm: false,
    creative: false,
    etc...
  }
```

And buttonToggle:

```
 buttonToggle = (event, name) => {
   event.persist();
   let { feeling } = this.state;
   feeling[name] = !feeling[name];
   this.setState({
    feeling
   });
 }
```

Comment: Great answer, welcome to SO. Concensus seems to be you have to rewrite the entire array back into setState. Is that a requirement, seems very non-performant.

Comment: @staypuftman It is redundant, but currently the only way. React doesn't handle nested state very well. An alternative approach would be either to 1. design (smaller) react components that do one specific task (and decrease the complexity of the state object) or 2. consider implementing redux into react. I recommend looking into both.

Comment: interesting, makes sense why all my attempts weren't working - I didn't have the right frame. Also interesting mentioning redux. This piece of state is actually in a context right now, but looks like I've hit the limit of what that can do. My site isn't super crazy so I think this will do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve your problem, you should first send the index of the element that is going to be modified to your toggle function :

```
onClick = {this.buttonToggle(index)}
```

Then tweak the function to receive both the index and the event.

Now, to modify your state array, copy it, change the value you are looking for, and put it back in your state :

```
buttonToggle = index => event => {
    event.persist();
    const feeling = [...this.state.feeling]; //Copy your array
    feeling[index] = !feeling[index];
    this.setState({ feeling }); 
}
```

You can also use `slice` to copy your array, or even directly send a `mapped` array where only one value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the whole array when get the event. And it is better to not mutate the existing state. I would recommend the following code

```
export default class StatePractice extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      feeling: [
        { name: "alert", status: false },
        { name: "calm", status: false },
        { name: "creative", status: false },
        { name: "productive", status: false },
        { name: "relaxed", status: false },
        { name: "sleepy", status: false },
        { name: "uplifted", status: false },
      ],
    };
  }

  buttonToggle = (index, value) => (event) => {
    event.persist();
    const toUpdate = { ...this.state.feeling[index], status: !value };
    const feeling = [...this.state.feeling];
    feeling.splice(index, 1, toUpdate);
    this.setState({
      feeling,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.feeling.map((stateObj, index) => {
          return (
            <button
              key={index}
              onClick={this.buttonToggle(index, stateObj.status)}
              value={stateObj.status}
            >
              {stateObj.status.toString()}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So you've the event nested inside of another function in buttonToggle - why?

Comment: I nested the buttonToggle to return function because I want to reuse index and status value from the item and the event handler is a function so I just combine them together :)